# How to transform List<String> into json in dart?

Tags: json, http, dart

This is my http get method in Dart:

```
Future<List<String>> get(String endpoint) async {
    HttpClientRequest httpClientRequest = await httpClient.getUrl(Uri.parse(_url + endpoint));
    _addCookies(httpClientRequest);
    final HttpClientResponse httpClientResponse = await httpClientRequest.close();
    return httpClientResponse
        .transform(utf8.decoder)
        .transform(const LineSplitter())
        .toList();
  }
```

I want to return a json object. How is the ideal way to do it? I don't think that converting this list back to a giant string is the best thing to do. Instead, I think I should use a transform to do the json conversion. If not possible, then I think I should not call `toList()` but instead get a full `String`. But then what is the better way to transform to json

Comment: do you mean json string?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return a json from a Dart http call / How to consume a stream entirely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60220679/how-to-return-a-json-from-a-dart-http-call-how-to-consume-a-stream-entirely)