# How to return a json from a Dart http call / How to consume a stream entirely?

Tags: json, http, dart

Here's my code that should return a json. I adapted this code from here https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/15110

```
  Stream _defaultReturn(HttpClientResponse httpClientResponse) {
    Stream response = httpClientResponse.
                      transform(utf8.decoder).
                      transform(json.decoder).
                      asyncMap((json) => jsonDecode(json));
    return response;
  }

  Future<dynamic> get(String endpoint) async {
    HttpClientRequest httpClientRequest =
        await httpClient.getUrl(Uri.parse(_url + endpoint));
    _addCookies(httpClientRequest);
    final HttpClientResponse httpClientResponse =
        await httpClientRequest.close();
    return _defaultReturn(httpClientResponse);
  }
```

I've put a return type of `Stream` into `_defaultReturn` because intellisense told me that giant thing returned me a `Stream`. I would actually want to receive a json (which should be a map). I think I migth consume or subscribe to this stream to get something useful. However, I don't see parsin json as stream as being useful. Don't I need the entire json before parsing? Shouldn't I simply accumulate everything into a `String` and then simply call `jsonDecode`?

Which is the most efficient way of returning a json from an http call? And how to do it?

Comment: It is expected that over the web, data is sent in chunks of bytes. Some libraries will transform it for you, with other you have to do it yourself. Take a look at how fetch is going about it. You would call 
`stream.json()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`json.decoder` will listen source stream and *always* transform its content to *just one* `Object`, so you can just return it with stream's `.first`:

```dart
Future<Object> get(String endpoint) async {
  var httpClientRequest = await httpClient.getUrl(Uri.parse(_url + endpoint));
  _addCookies(httpClientRequest);
  final httpClientResponse = await httpClientRequest.close();
  return httpClientResponse
           .transform(utf8.decoder)
           .transform(json.decoder)
           .first;
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```dart
var jsonObject = await myHttpClient.get(myEndpoint);
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a package named [JSON_Serializable](https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable) that you could make use of. Generate your object class, and you could map your HTTP return to the class.

```
final response = await http.get(url, headers: await setHeaders());
dynamic parsed = jsonDecode(await response.body);
YourItemsList = List<YourItems>.from(
    parsed['data'].map((i) => YourItems.fromJson(i)));
```

Your class generation will include both functions below:

```
  factory YourItemsList.fromJson(Map<dynamic, dynamic> json) =>
  _$YourItemsListFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$YourItemsListToJson(this);
```

Comment: I'm using this class, but I created a generic method that interprets a generic json because I have so many models: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60189464/10116440. And your http class is different than mine, this one does not have support for cookies, that's why I chose the dart native one.