# Flutter http client gives FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1) <!DOCTYPE html>

Tags: http, flutter, dart

I'm using this:

```
Future<Object> get(String endpoint) async {
  var httpClientRequest = await httpClient.getUrl(Uri.parse(_url + endpoint));
  _addCookies(httpClientRequest);
  final httpClientResponse = await httpClientRequest.close();
  return httpClientResponse
           .transform(utf8.decoder)
           .transform(json.decoder)
           .first;
}
```

from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/60344779/10116440

to get a json from my API. But I get

```
Unhandled exception:
FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)
<!DOCTYPE html>
^

#0      _ChunkedJsonParser.fail (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1394:5)
#1      _ChunkedJsonParser.parseNumber (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1261:9)
#2      _ChunkedJsonParser.parse (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:926:22)
#3      _JsonStringDecoderSink.addSlice (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1480:13)
#4      _JsonStringDecoderSink.add (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1485:5)
#5      _ConverterStreamEventSink.add (dart:convert/chunked_conversion.dart:74:18)
#6      _SinkTransformerStreamSubscription._handleData (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart:122:24)
#7      _RootZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1316:10)
#8      _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:338:11)
#9      _BufferingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:265:7)
#10     _SinkTransformerStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart:70:11)
#11     _EventSinkWrapper.add (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart:17:11)
#12     _StringAdapterSink.add (dart:convert/string_conversion.dart:238:11)
#13     _StringAdapterSink.addSlice (dart:convert/string_conversion.dart:243:7)
#14     _Utf8ConversionSink.addSlice (dart:convert/string_conversion.dart:314:20)
#15     _Utf8ConversionSink.add (dart:convert/string_conversion.dart:307:5)
#16     _ConverterStreamEventSink.add (dart:convert/chunked_conversion.dart:74:18)
#17     _SinkTransformerStreamSubscription._handleData (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart:122:24)
#18     _RootZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1316:10)
#19     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:338:11)
#20     _BufferingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:265:7)
#21     _ForwardingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:134:11)
#22     _ForwardingStream._handleData (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:100:10)
#23     _ForwardingStreamSubscription._handleData (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:166:13)
#24     _RootZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1316:10)
#25     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:338:11)
#26     _DelayedData.perform (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:593:14)
#27     _StreamImplEvents.handleNext (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:709:11)
#28     _PendingEvents.schedule.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:669:7)
#29     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:43:21)
#30     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:52:5)
#31     _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:118:13)
#32     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:175:5)
```

but I'm positive that the API returns json, not HTML.

What is going on? My API doesn't even return HTML, how can it complain that there's a doctype?

Comment: Giving people time to answer is fine. Here you've gotten a perfect answer so what are you waiting for? If the answer does not answer your question, clarify the question. It sure does look like a correct answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, most web app servers reply with various HTML pages when an error occurs (404 not found, 401 not authorized, 500 internal exception etc.)

Try checking the HTTP status code of the response instead of assuming it's always a successful JSON response. If the status code is not 200, it may not be a JSON.